# I need to iterate over list items with for loop to use this items to filter pandas data frame columns and save the return columns to new data frame,

Tags: python, pandas

I need to iterate over list items with for loop to use this item to filter pandas data frame columns and save the return columns to a new data frame, then do the calculation on the new data frame but each time I run the for loop return only one item no all the list items.

**This is image for the data frame and my code**
[image]

Comment: Please put the code in the question itself, not as a screen capture. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3216427

Comment: And, you have a return statement inside the for loop. You might just need to outdent the `return` line.

Comment: thanks so much, you right, "return" was my mistake once remove it evrything solved, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

at the bottom of your for loop, the return statement will end the loop on the first item in the collection every time. instead of return, add the data to an array or vector and at the end of the loop return the whole collection.

Comment: thanks so much, you right, "return" was my mistake once remove it evrything solved, thanks again